# Create new array by filter origin array

Tags: javascript, array, lodash.js

I'm getting an array and I needed to find a duplicate ID inside:

```
var aDuplicateId = [];
            //get the duplicated configuration indexs
            for (var i = 0; i < aConfigurations.length; i++) {
                //in case the index is the duplicate array skip
                if (aDuplicateId.indexOf(i) >= 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                var iId = aConfigurations[i]._metadata.id;
                //find duplicate ids
                var iIndex = _.findLastIndex(aConfigurations, function(o) {
                    return o._metadata.id === iId;
                });
                //add the duplicate id index to array
                if (iIndex >= 0 && iIndex !== i) {
                    aDuplicateId.push(iIndex);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So essentially, you're just getting the unique configuration IDs. This can easily be done by converting your `aConfigurations` into an array of IDs and using [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to weed out duplicates. Then you can convert the set instance back into an array using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

```
const configIds = aConfigurations.map(config => config._metadata.id);
const configIdsSet = new Set(configIds);
const configIdsUnique = Array.from(configIdsSet);
```

Alternatively, without ES6, you can just use [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to collect IDs as keys of an object and then use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to extract the keys into an array.

```
var configMap = aConfigurations.reduce(function(configs, config){
  configs[config._metadata.id] = true;
  return configs;
}, {});

var configIdsUnique = Object.keys(configMap);
```